# Magento2.3.3 Facing Error during Data migration

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento2.3, eav, data-migration

I am trying to migartion from Magneto1.9.3.10 to Magento2.3.3 but I am facing error during [Eav Step] data migration like:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

Please check below screenshots:

[image]
If anyone having idea about this error on how to get resolved then please share your thoughts for the same.

I am waiting for your feedback to get resolved this error.

Any help would be more appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/103#issuecomment-273165753

Comment: Hi @Rv Singh, did you get the solution for this ?